# Action Mailer not sending mails although the logs say it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have the following code in my registration controller

```
def new

  Rails.logger.debug "#{params[:email]}"

  if !params[:email].blank? && !params[:invoke].blank? && params[:invoke].casecmp('Send') == 0
    MyMailer.send_email(params[:email]).deliver
   end 

end
```

My params[:email] gets populated correctly.

in my_mailer.rb i have the following code

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base

default from: 'someaddress@yahoo.com'

def send_email(emailaddress) 
@emailaddress=emailaddress
Rails.logger.debug "{#{emailaddress}}"
mail(to: @emailaddress ,subject: 'asdasd')
end
end
```

I have set the following properties in `development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I have also done the smtp configurations in `setup_mail.rb` under the initializers

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address                => "smtp.yahoo.com",
    :port                   => 587,
    :domain                 => "yahoo.com",
    :user_name              => "someaddress@yahoo.com",
    :password               => "somepass",
    :authentication     => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto   => true
}
```

My logs say that the mail has been sent to the respective person but my gmail shows no mail has arrived . Not even in the spams. Is there any configuration settings i am missing out on ?

Comment: i had a similar problem with gmail when i was trying to send an email to linked accounts. i needed to send to a different account, just try an email of a coworker or something on a not yahoo domain.

Comment: It's unlikely this is a code error. Sign up for an alternative SMTP provider and to rule out external errors.

Comment: i had exactly same issue